# how to force android system to recycle all background activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there API or commands to force Android system to recycle all background activities no matter there is enough resource or not? And how to check all the activities' status to check that the activity is actually killed?

There is an API called killBackgroundProcesses(), but this API is killed the whole process, I am wondering how to only kill some activities without killing the whole process.

As the android dev guide page says below, I am looking for the first way.

[activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

> If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity
>   from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its
>   process.

Comment: its the job of garbage collector to free memory. Look at the activiy lifecycle methods. Also look at the activity back stack from the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way:

**Settings -> Developer options -> Apps -> Don't keep activities**

Check that box, and you are good to go.

Cheers.

Comment: Correct way, I use this method to test the saveInstance of activity, otherwise it not an easy thing let system recycle the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so Android gives you the information of Activities are in background (i.e in Paused or Stopped State). Even if Activity Stack as well will give you the access of activity at Top.

Possible Solutions : 
1. If at all you want to destroy the service , better to call finish() after startActivity() method. 
2. If you want to periodically destroy all the background activities. You should implement your own activity stack. Which does pushToStack() on start of new activity and popFromStack() and then activity.finish();